# Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile

Estoy trabajando con makefiles,al compilar el siguiente codigo la opción de random trabaja perfectamente, pero en la opción de introducir la matriz mediante el teclado sale esto `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`, podrían decirme por qué sale esto o que esta mal en el codigo, porfavor.

El error se origina después de ingresar la matriz (`user(b, N, P);`). Creo que el error está en la función `printm(b, N, P);`.

function.h

```
#ifndef function_H
#define function_H

int user(int **m, int N, int P);
void printm(int **m, int N, int P);
int generator(int **m, int N, int P);
void lmax(int **m, int N, int P);

#endif
```

function.cc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "function.h"

using namespace std;

int user(int **m, int N, int P)
{
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<P; j++)
        {   
            cin >> m[i][j];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void printm(int **m, int N, int P)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<N; i++);
    {
        for (int j=0; j<P; j++)
        {
            cout << " " << m[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int generator(int **m, int N, int P)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<P; j++)
        {
            m[i][j] = rand()%50-0;
            cout << " " << m[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}

void lmax(int **m, int N, int P)
{
    int j_max;
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        j_max = 0;
        for (int j=1; j<P; j++)
            if (m[i][j_max] < m[i][j]) 
            {
                j_max = j;
            }
        m[i][j_max] = 0;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<P; j++)  {
            cout << " " << m[i][j] << "\t";  }
        cout << endl;  }
    cout << endl;

    bool kl = true;
    for (int i=1; i<N; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
        {
            if (m[i][j] != m[j][i])
                kl = false;
        }
    }
    if (kl)
    {
        cout << " Symetric matrix." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << " Not symetric matrix." << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

test.cc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "function.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N, P, **a, **b;
    char ch;

    cout << "\n 1 - Initialize matrix by using a random number generator." << endl;
    cout << " 2 - Initialize matrix via user input." << endl;
    cout << " 0 - Exit." << endl;
    cout << "\n Your choice: ";

    do {
        ch = getchar();
        switch(ch)
        {
            case '1':
                cout << "\n Rows: ";
                cin >> N;  
                cout << " Columns: ";
                cin >> P;  cout << endl;
                a = new int *[N];
                for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
                {
                    a[i] = new int [P];
                }
                generator(a, N, P);
                lmax(a, N, P);
                return 0;

            case '2':
                cout << "\n Rows: ";
                cin >> N;  
                cout << " Columns: ";
                cin >> P;  cout << endl; 
                b = new int *[N];
                for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
                {
                    b[i] = new int [P];
                }
                user(b, N, P);
                printm(b, N, P);
                lmax(b, N, P);
                return 0;
        }
    }
    while(ch != '0');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola Neon, como consejo general: trata de quitar todo el código que no contribuya al error. O sea, trata de mantener el código más simple posible que reproduce el error. Si la opción 1 funciona bien, quítala (no nos interesa para contestar la duda). También trata de poner `cout` o usar un depurador (_debugger_) para ver **exactamente en qué línea** está saltando el error. Es lo mismo que haría yo para resolver tu problema :)

Comment: @astrojuanlu Gracias por el consejo, estoy trabajando desde la terminal, y el codigo esta guardado en el editor gedit, al producirse el error no muestra en linea se encuentra, pero marcaré en la que creo que esta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estas son las funciones que tenía error. Ya están corregidas.

```
int user(int **m, int N, int P)
{
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<P; j++)
        {   
            cin >> m[i][j];
        }
    }

     return 0;
}

void printm(int **m, int N, int P)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<P; j++)
        {
            cout << " " << m[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Tenías un mal return en la función `user` y un `;` en el primer ciclo de la función `printm`

Comment: sigue saliendo el mismo error sino que antes imprime 'j, n_de_rows, j, 0'

Comment: Lo acabo de probar, no me fije lo que hace después de que formas la matriz pero me termina bien con un `Not symetric matrix.` Que datos le ingresas?

Comment: ingreso un matriz de dos por dos, todos los elementos en una solo línea.

Comment: Acabo de compilarlo y probarlo tambien con una matriz de 2x2 en os x y linux y funciona bien sin segmentation fault, si corregiste las funciones que te dije? se me hace raro que a mi me funcione y  a ti no

Comment: Perdón no me fijé bien en el punto y coma, ese era el error, ahora funciona. Gracias

Answer (score 3):

En esta respuesta voy a asumir que una exigencia de la práctica es usar memoria dinámica. Si no es así deberías plantearte reescribir el programa usando vectores o encapsulando el uso de memoria dinámica en una clase (si no infringes ninguna regla marcada por la práctica).

El código duplicado suele ser buen amigo de los errores porque ante la necesidad de realizar un cambio o realizas exactamente el mismo cambio en todos los sitios donde estén los duplicados o el programa va a empezar a dar problemas.

Vamos a hacer un poco de refactorización a ver si conseguimos un código más legible.

Tu programa maneja matrices. Salvo que sea una exigencia explícita de la práctica lo ideal sería que toda la información concerniente a la matriz viajase siempre junta:

```
struct Matrix
{
  int** datos;
  int Filas;
  int Columnas;
};
```

De momento no vamos a complicar el ejemplo con el uso de constructores.

El caso es que en tu ejercicio estás creando matrices en dos sitios distintos. Se plantea entonces interesante la idea de disponer de un mecanismo que permita crear una matriz. Una función se adapta perfectamente a nuestras necesidades

```
Matrix NuevaMatriz(int filas, int columnas)
{
  Matrix matriz;
  matriz.datos = new int[filas];

  for( int i=0; i<filas; i++ )
    matriz.datos[i] = new int[columnas];

  return matriz;
}
```

Por supuesto no podemos plantearnos en un programa hacer reservas de memoria sin limpiarla posteriormente... toca crear otra función para liberar la memoria reservada:

```
void BorrarMatriz(Matrix & matriz)
{
  for( int i=0; i<filas; i++ )
    delete[] matriz.datos[i];

  delete[] matriz.datos;

  matriz.datos = nullptr;
}
```

Otro elemento que tienes duplicado es la función para rellenar la matriz. En tu caso concreto podrías realizar esto con una única función, ya que la única diferencia radica en el origen de datos (entrada estándar o generador aleatorio).

Es en esta parte de tu código donde se encuentra tu error. Compara detenidamente las dos funciones:

```
int user(int **m, int N, int P)
{
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<P; j++)
        {   
            cin >> m[i][j];
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

int generator(int **m, int N, int P)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<P; j++)
        {
            m[i][j] = rand()%50-0;
            cout << " " << m[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Pese a hacer exactamente lo mismo lucen bastante diferentes... sobretodo es llamativo encontrarnos con un `return` en la función `user` dentro del primer bucle (tu error).

¿Cómo se puede simplificar esto? Hay todo un abanico de opciones. Aquí tienes algunas ideas:

Una opción, dado que recorrer la matriz suele ser algo recurrente en tu ejercicio puedes encapsular dicho bucle en una función y ejecutar "algo" en cada iteración:

```
void MatrixLoop(Matrix& matriz, std::function<void(int&,int,int)> func)
{
  for( int i=0; i<matriz.Filas; i++ )
  {
    for( int j=0; j<matriz.Columnas; j++ )
    {
      // A la función le proporcionamos el valor actual de la matriz por
      // referencia para poder modificarlo, la fila y la columna.
      func(matriz[i][j],i,j);
    }
  }
}

void RellenarPorUsuario(int& dato, int fila, int columna)
{
  std::cout << "Valor para (" << fila << "," << columna << "): ";
  std::cin >> dato;
}

void RellenarAleatoriamente(int& dato, int fila, int columna)
{
  static bool init = false;

  if( !init )
  {
    init = true;
    srand(time(NULL)); 
  }

  dato = rand()%50;
}

// ...
case 1:
{
  int filas, columnas;
  std::cout << "\n Rows: ";
  std::cin >> filas;  
  std::cout << " Columns: ";
  std::cin >> columnas;

  Matrix matriz = NuevaMatriz(filas,columnas);
  MatrixLoop(matriz, RellenarAleatoriamente);
  // ...
  BorrarMatriz(matriz);

  break;
}

case 2:
{
  int filas, columnas;
  std::cout << "\n Rows: ";
  std::cin >> filas;  
  std::cout << " Columns: ";
  std::cin >> columnas;

  Matrix matriz = NuevaMatriz(filas,columnas);
  MatrixLoop(matriz, RellenarPorUsuario);
  // ...
  BorrarMatriz(matriz);

  break;
}
```

También se pueden usar `lambdas` para conseguir un código más legible:

```
void MatrixLoop(Matrix& matriz, std::function<void(int&,int,int)> func)
{
  for( int i=0; i<matriz.Filas; i++ )
  {
    for( int j=0; j<matriz.Columnas; j++ )
    {
      // A la función le proporcionamos el valor actual de la matriz por
      // referencia para poder modificarlo, la fila y la columna.
      func(matriz[i][j],i,j);
    }
  }
}

void RellenarPorUsuario(Matrix& matriz)
{
  std::function<void(int&,int,int)> lambda = [](int& dato, int fila, int columna )
  {
    std::cout << "Valor para (" << fila << "," << columna << "): ";
    std::cin >> dato;
  };

  MatrixLoop(matriz,lambda);
}

void RellenarAleatoriamente(Matrix& matriz)
{
  std::function<void(int&,int,int)> lambda = [](int& dato, int, int)
  {
    dato = rand()%50;
  };

  srand(time(NULL)); 
  MatrixLoop(matriz,lambda);
}

// ...
case 1:
{
  int filas, columnas;
  std::cout << "\n Rows: ";
  std::cin >> filas;  
  std::cout << " Columns: ";
  std::cin >> columnas;

  Matrix matriz = NuevaMatriz(filas,columnas);
  RellenarAleatoriamente(matriz);
  // ...
  break;
}

case 2:
{
  int filas, columnas;
  std::cout << "\n Rows: ";
  std::cin >> filas;  
  std::cout << " Columns: ";
  std::cin >> columnas;

  Matrix matriz = NuevaMatriz(filas,columnas);
  RellenarPorUsuario(matriz);
  // ...

  break;
}
```

Y bueno, ya solo faltaría imprimir la matriz:

```
void Imprimir(Matrix const& matriz)
{
  auto lambda = [](int& dato, int, int columna)
  {
    if( columna == 0 )
      std::cout << '\n';
    else
      std::cout << ' ';

    std::cout << dato;
  }

  LoopMatrix(matriz, lambda);
}
```

Otra opción, con un código más sencillo y modesto pero también más rígido, podría ser que disponer de una única función `RellenarMatriz` que reciba un `bool` (o incluso un `enum` si quieres ser más flexible). En función del valor de esa variable tomará una entrada de datos u otra:

```
void RellenarMatriz(Matrix & matriz, bool esRandom)
{
  srand(time(NULL)); 

  for( int i=0; i<matriz.Filas; i++ )
  {
    for( int j=0; j<matriz.Columnas; j++ )
    {
      if( esRandom )
        matriz[i][j] = rand()%50;
      else
      {
        std::cout << "Valor para (" << i<< "," << j<< "): ";
        std::cin >> matriz[i][j];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

De una forma similar podrías actuar ante la entrada de los valores `fila` y `columna`, eso ya te lo dejo a ti para practicar si te ves con energías.

Del **segmentation fault** que mencionas no veo ni rastro, pero también es cierto que falta la implementación de `lmax`...

Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, pero exactamente, un requisito de mi práctica es usar memoria dinámica y sin estructura

Comment: Lo que te he explicado se puede hacer igual sin estructuras